# python way to make integer class with additional data

Tags: python, class

Good day! 
I'm think about class in python to store a map tiles inside, such as

```
map = [[WorldTile() for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
```

i create class

```
class WorldTile:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.resource = val
        self.objects = dict()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.resource

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (str(self.resource))

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.resource, other)

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.resource += other
        return self.resource

    def __sub__(self, other):
        self.resource -= other
        return self.resource
```

but something going wrong. 
i'l try

```
x = WorldTile.WorldTile(7)
print type(x), id(x), x
print x > 2, x < 5, x > 0
#x += 5
print type(x), id(x), x
print x, str(x), type(x)
print x.objects
```

they work fine, but if i'l uncomment line `x += 5` x becoming an `<type 'int'>`

totally, i'm want to have class, with i can work as integer ( `x = x +-*\ y` etc ), but also can access additional fields if necessary ( `x.objects` )
i think i need override assignemet method, but that not possible in python. Any other way for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `__iadd__` for `+=`.

However, your current `__add__` is broken. You could fix it by making it return a (new) instance of `WorldTile` rather than an `int`:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return WorldTile(self.resource + other)
```

This will work for both `+` and `+=` (handling `self.objects` is left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: Interesting, I was making it to look like an int, with `+`, and you are making it to look like `WorldTile`.

Comment: This is the correct way for classes which should model their behaviour after immutable builtins.